# Units in matrix rings over non commutative ring with unity

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, reference-request, determinant

1)This book "introduction to Rings and Modules" by C. Mussili, says determinant of a matrix over non commutative ring is not defined. But in defining the determinant of a matrix where the commutativity of the ring is used.

2) Please suggest some texts to study group of units of matrix rings over non commutative rings.

Comment: The definition does not use commutativity, but most properties do.

Comment: Not "the determinant over noncommutative ring is not defined" but rather "the usual definition is not suitable" There are certainly definitions of determinants used with noncommutative fields.

Comment: Cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3643151/96384

Comment: @rschwieb Why the usual definition is not suitable ?

Comment: @MeetPatel This is not a precise reason, but an intuitive one: without commutativity you can't be as cavalier with the order of multiplications in the definition.  For a $2\times 2$ matrix the determinant is $ab-cd=ba-cd=ab-dc=ba-dc$. But for a noncommutative ring, they could potentially all be different. Which one do you want? It is unclear. So, one has to be more careful.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in this article:

Gelʹfand, I. M.; Retakh, V. S. Determinants of matrices over noncommutative rings. (Russian) ; translated from *Funktsional. Anal. i Prilozhen*. **25** (1991), no. 2, 13--25, 96 *Funct. Anal. Appl.* **25** (1991), no. 2, 91--102

and in this book

Okniński, Jan. *Semigroups of matrices*, Series in Algebra, 6. World Scientific Publishing Co., Inc., River Edge, NJ, 1998. xiv+311 pp. ISBN: 981-02-3445-7

In particular Chapter 9 is about matrix algebras $M_n(D)$ over a division algebra $D$.