# Prove that $\det (AB)=\det A \det B$ when entries of the matrices are in a non-commutative ring $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, determinant

It is well-known that $\det (AB)=\det A \det B$ for real square matrices, but what if the matrices have entries in a non-commutative ring $R$?
By the Principle of Permanence, it suffices to prove the identity in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\{x_{ij}\},\{y_{ij}\}]$, because there is a unique homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}[\{x_{ij}\},\{y_{ij}\}]$ to $R$. But it seems that it makes the problem even harder. I have no idea how to prove using this approach. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This may help answer your quesiton: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/81948/inverse-of-a-matrix-over-a-non-commutative-ring.

Comment: How do you define the determinant to begin with? There's no way to define a determinant over noncommutative rings (even skew-fields, for that matter) having nice properties as in the commutative case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As egreg noted in a comment, it's not clear what "determinant" should mean over non-commutative rings, but let me suppose that you arbitrarily decided that 
$$
\det\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}=ad-bc,
$$
even though other choices like $da-cb$ would seem equally good. What I write below can easily be adjusted to work with these alternative definitions.

Consider two elements $a,b$ in your ring that don't commute. Then for the matrices 
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\ 0&a\end{pmatrix} \text{ and }
B=\begin{pmatrix}b&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix},
$$
we have 
$$
AB=\begin{pmatrix}b&0\\0&a\end{pmatrix},
$$
and so $\det AB=ba$ while $\det A\cdot\det B=a\cdot b$.

Comment: Brilliant. But what if I change the claim to $\det (AB)=\det B \det A$, will the identity holds?

Comment: @Howardli621 No, the same two matrices will give a counterexample to the new claim if you just call the first one $B$ and the second one $A$.